# Postgres: Joining Tables on ID nested within JSON

Tags: json, postgresql

I have created 2 tables in my postgres db, each contains two columns, a uuid column, and a column that contains JSON.

**Table A (Provinces):**

Column 1 (ProvinceID):

"112233"

Column 2 (JSON):

```
{
    "id": "123",
    "name":"Ontario",
    "cities": [
     "456",
     "789",
     "112",
     "141"
    ],
    "status": 0
}
```

**Table B (Cities):**

Column 1 (CityId):

"465"

Column 2 (JSON):

```
{
    "id": "456",
    "name":"Toronto",
    "NHL Team": 1
    "Population": 4000000
}
```

In this example, a province has a one to many relationship with cities. What I've failed to do so far is join a province in table A (Provinces) to all of its cities in table B (Cities). I'm failing to do so because the CityId is stored as a nested field in Table A (Provinces).

e.g.

```
FROM Provinces JOIN Cities on (Provinces.JSON->'Cities' = Cities.CityId)
```

I've experimented with the built in JSON functions #>, ->, json_array_elements - I can't seem to find a solution that returns correct output.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just because you can store json doesn't mean you should.

Comment: I would be only too happy to be rid of the JSON in the DB. It has been nothing but a pain thus far.

Comment: Pg's json features are still limited, and json support will probably never have all the full relational capabilities. Its great when you need it and as an alternative to EAV but its no substitute for relational decomposition. Time permitting it'll have a play with this tomorrow though since nobody's jumped in with suggestions.

Comment: I think relational decomp is what I would have preferred - as always, time and resource constraints for going that route - not to mention the stigma that relational is an outdated way of thinking.

Comment: @CraigRinger `json_array_elements` returns type json - even if it is converted to text or str, it retains the double quotes around the ID - this causes the join to fail because 421 != "421"; `json_array_elements` also will not let me use **->>** in the function. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's an annoying omission in 9.3's json support. 9.4 adds `json_array_elements_text`. IIRC there's some mailing list discussion about workarounds, but I don't recall the details. Searching for `json_array_elements_text` may prove useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from
    (
        select
            id, name,
            json_array_elements(JSON -> 'cities')::text::int as CityId,
            status
        from provinces
    ) provinces p
    inner join
    Cities c using (CityId)
```

In the posted JSON data the `cities` property has a lower case first letter. If it has a first capital letter then change the code above.

If `CityId` in the `Cities` table is of type `text` then there is no need to cast `JSON -> 'cities'` to `integer`

BTW that looks like bad database design. JSON is not a substitute for good design.

Comment: Fully agree on the very unfriendly design. It was stored in MSSQL before and getting a copy over to Postgres is a huge win for me. This is a schema that I've had to inherit from another system and I didn't really get a great deal of say in the matter.

Comment: Going to accept this answer because the subquery was helpful in completing this join properly. Only thing holding me back is the omission of `json_array_elements_text` from 9.3.